Google Cloud Run Job - Terminate a Task after Timelimit without error
Good morning,
I'm trying to run a scheduled Google Cloud Run Job. It works very well but I struggle with time limitation.
The job should check a mail-inbox for unread Messages and answer them automatically. (works fine with python)
The Job should terminate after 4 hours by himself, so i configured a timelimit of 4 hours inside the job configuration.
The Problem: GCR interprets this as an error timeout (ERROR LOG: "Terminating task because it has reached the maximum timeout of 14400 seconds.") an restarts the job.
I configured restarts in case of unexpected connection errors, so i dont want to set them to zero.
Is it possible to terminate the task by timelimit without an error with job configuration or do i have to put my timelit/count of runs inside the python sourcefile?
I tryed to put it in the souce file, but I cant predict the exact runtime, because if there are more than one mails to answer in one checkup loop, it sleeps for some seconds. Otherwise there occure errors because the mailprovider cant send a lot of mails within milliseconds.
I need the task to be killed after nearby exactly 4 hours.
If its not possible with GCR, I have to handle it inside the code, but dealing with inside Job configuration would be the easy way.
Thank you very much!
